# Set Cookies with form button

Tags: cookies

I am trying to set a cookie with the onclick of a button. I am still very new to cookies and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is the button and the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setCookie(){
        var exp = new Date( );
        exp.setMinutes( exp.getMinutes( ) + 5 );
        document.cookie("cookieOne=red; expires=" + exp.toUTCString( ));
    }
</script>
<input name="addtocart" type="button" value="Add To Cart" onClick="setCookie()" />
```

I thought this would work but when I go to another page it prints nothing. Here is the second page.

```
<link href="css/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Table_01">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     document.writeln( document.cookie );
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Again I just hit the cookies section of the javascript book I am learning from and this simple test doesnt seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `;path=/` and see if it fixes things.

EDIT: whoops, nothing to see, move along...

Comment: would I set the path like this?document.cookie("cookieOne=red; expires=" + exp.toUTCString( ) + ";path=/;");